# image zooming while mouseover on the image in tilelist using flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I have collection of images getting from xml. That images placed in tilelist, i need zooming while mouseover which one image. please let me know..using flex 3.

Answer (score 0):

mhh, add a new listener (mouseOver or onMouseOver) to the image. 
if event is dispatched, then scale the image up.

Damian

Comment: Thanks.i tried it. but i need mouseover zooming image is display outof tilelist.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the links below :

[FlexWiz](http://flexwiz.amosl.com/flex/spark-list-with-zoom-effect/) , http://www.rockholla.org/technology/2011/01/07/flex-as3-pan-zoom-component and [Adobe Pan Zoom Component](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/samples/fig_panzoom.html)